# Jquery AutoComplete data for each row

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello In my jquery I want to populate data in form fields of current row. I will have multiple fields with same classes and my this code works but problem which I am facing is, this code change of all the row but i want to change only my current row data 
**Here is my fiddle**
https://jsfiddle.net/1bfbtoxw/

**And here is my jquery**

```
$(".enginenum").autocomplete({
    source: "includes/modvehicleSale/search-engine.php",
    minLength: 1,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        var item = ui.item;
            if(item) {
                $('.txtchassis').val(item.ChassisNo);
                $('.txtdescription').val(item.BikeDescription);
                $('txtselling').val(item.SellingAmount);
            }
        }
})
```

Comment: That's why we use `class`es; to do a single show use `id`s

Comment: tried with ids too but nothing work, could you please forward the solution??

Comment: not working with the IDs

Comment: How do I identify `the current row`? you need to post more html

Comment: Try to find closest class with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[A sample fiddle first](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/1bfbtoxw/3/)**

Assuming that you have `.row` as parent for each `row` you can refer the **current row** with `$(this).closest('.row')` and can use `.find` to get the related elements of that row. So your changes would be as below:

```
$(".enginenum").autocomplete({
    source: "includes/modvehicleSale/search-engine.php",
    minLength: 1,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        var item = ui.item;
            if(item) {
                $(this).closest('.row').find('.txtchassis').val(item.ChassisNo);
                $(this).closest('.row').find('.txtdescription').val(item.BikeDescription);
                $(this).closest('.row').find('.txtselling').val(item.SellingAmount);
            }
        }
});
```

**Please make a note, that `id`s have to be unique to follow the standards.**

Comment: Anytime.. Happy Coding.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your jsfiddle is not setup properly.

I added the class to your other inputs and change the js code to below:

```
const ac_settings = {
        source: "includes/modvehicleSale/search-engine.php",
        minLength: 1,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            var item = ui.item;
                if(item) {
                    $('.txtchassis').val(item.ChassisNo);
                                         $('.txtdescription').val(item.BikeDescription);
                    $('txtselling').val(item.SellingAmount);
                }
            }
    }

$.each($(".enginenum"), function() {
     $(this).autocomplete(ac_settings)
})
//$(".enginenum").autocomplete()
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1bfbtoxw/2/

Comment: Have you change the source "includes/modvehicleSale/search-engine.php " to include your own domain?

Answer (score 0):

try selecting the closest row, like this

```
var row = $(event.target).closest(".row");
```

then use this row as container in your selectors

```
$('.txtchassis', row)
```

code will be:

```
    $(".enginenum").autocomplete({
        source: "includes/modvehicleSale/search-engine.php",
        minLength: 1,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            var row = $(event.target).closest(".row");
            var item = ui.item;
                if(item) {
                    $('.txtchassis', row).val(item.ChassisNo);
                    $('.txtdescription', row).val(item.BikeDescription);
                    $('txtselling', row).val(item.SellingAmount);
                }
            }
    })
```